# Error in Building Hive Projects in VSTS CI/CD

Tags: c#, hive, continuous-integration, azure-devops, cd

I am facing an issue when building a Hive project in VSTS. The error message is here :

> C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\DataLake\MsBuild\1.0\Hive.targets(31,5):
>   Error MSB4062: The
>   "Microsoft.WindowsAzure.HDIStudio.ProjectSystem.HiveCompilerTask" task
>   could not be loaded from the assembly
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StreamAnalytics.Common.CompileService.dll.
>   Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StreamAnalytics.Common.CompileService.dll' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>   Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly
>   and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a
>   public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

- I am using a private agent for the build and I also have updated the Data Lake Analytics tools to the newest version.
- When I build the projects in the machine used for the private agent, it builds successfully but when I build it in the VSTS it throws the error above.

Can somebody help me with my problem? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Please try configure Stream Analytics tools manually to build the Hive project in VSTS Build pipeline with following document to check if the problem still exist: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/stream-analytics/stream-analytics-tools-for-visual-studio-cicd

Comment: Did you run the build agent with the same account you used to build the project manually? Have you tried to reboot the agent machine?